# Cannot understand how the DML works in this code

Tags: soql, dml

I'm very new to apex and have just started learning. I was going through soql and came across this code that I'm not able to understand.

```
Opportunity opp = [SELECT Id, Name FROM Opportunity WHERE Id = '0068c00000vF5kbAAC'];
opp.Name = 'test 2';
opp.IsPrimaryLead__c = true;
update opp;

System.debug('val 1 ='+opp.Name);
System.debug('val 2 ='+opp.IsPrimaryLead__c);
```

What I understand is that to access certain fields from an object, we need to query them all using SOQL. When I execute this code, I'm able to see both debug statements printing in the log. But I don't understand how is the IsPrimaryLead__c still being accessed and update since it's not being queried.

Comment: You cannot access a field to read without either first querying it or setting it. You can set any field that is in principle writable (not all fields are writable, such as auto numbers and formulae).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assignment and access are different things.

As long as the field exists on the SObject (and you have the permissions to read/write the field), then it doesn't matter if you query the field or not *when you are assigning a value to the field*.

The only time that you need to query a field is when you read/access the value, and even then that only applies to the record instances returned by a query (any query).

If you use the `new` keyword to create a new instance of an SObject type (Account, Contact, My_Custom_Object__c, etc...), then you can access fields that haven't been set without an issue (they'll just be null in that case).

```java
Opportunity opp1 = new Opportunity();
// You can assign values without issue
// The LHS (left-hand side) of the assignment is not subject to the "must be queried"
//   rule
opp1.Name = 'My Opp';

// Because this object instance was not returned by a query, we can also access fields that
//   haven't been set without issue
system.debug(opp1.Description == opp1.Name); // Should print false

// Note that queries always return a List<SObject>
// Salesforce allows us to assign the result of a query to a single SObject instance
//   when the query returns _exactly one row_ as a quality-of-life improvement thing
Opportunity opp2 = [SELECT Id, Name FROM Opportunity WHERE Id = <some Id here>];

// Accessing a field that wasn't queried is an issue (when the SObject instance originates
//   from a query)
//system.debug(opp2.Description == opp2.Name); // This would throw an exception

// Assigning a value to a field is perfectly fine
// The access happens on the LHS of the assignment
opp2.Description = opp2.Name;

// Once set, a field can be accessed on the RHS (right-hand side) or used in other expressions
opp2.Other_Field__c = opp2.Description;
system.debug(opp2.Description == opp2.Name); // This will return true
```